# Manual navigation doesn't work in ui-router for AngularJS 1.7

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following state configuration:

```
function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/app/home/template/home.html",
            controller: "HomeController as homeController"
        });
        .state("user", {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/user",
            template: "<ui-view/>"
        })
        .state("user.list", {
            url: "/list",
            templateUrl: "/app/user/template/user.list.html",
            controller: "UserListController as userListController"
        });
}
```

user.list.html contains a table of users, home.html constains the link to the user.list.html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="user.list" role="button">View All Users</a>
```

When I start the application and go to the `localhost:8080`, it displays me home.html. Then, when I click on the button "View All Users", it displays me user.list.html and I see a table of users. Evething works fine, but **the problem starts** when I try to reload the page (pressing F5) or when I manually navigate to the `localhost:8080/user/list`. It displays me 404 error page. **My question is:** why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with AngularJS but your web server. You need to configure the server you are using to route 404 errors to your home.html. When you request `localhost:8080/user/list` your server does not find a resource for `/user/list`.

Think of what happens when you load localhost:8080. You get home.html and your AngularJS app is initialised. When your change the route from localhost:8080 to `localhost:8080/user/list` the route handler from ui-router fires. No http request is sent to the web server. When you manually type the route or hit F5 you send a http request to the web server looking for the resource /user/list which does not exist on the server so you get a 404 not found error. You need to configure 404 errors to load home.html which will load up the AngularJS app.

Comment: When I go to the localhost:8080 , I'm getting index.html and 'home' state initialized that populates index.html with home.html partial view (it's not full html page with html, head and body tags)

Comment: I'm using Spring framework (which accordings to the Java language) on the backend.

Comment: Then serve up index.html on 404s

Comment: Sorry I have never used Java or Spring Framework so I can't give you any pointers on configuration, but you need to get the Spring Framework to serve your index.html file for 404 errors. It should not be difficult, I have done this with both ASP.NET and NodeJS servers.

Comment: Thank you for the idea what happens behind the scene;) I didn't think about it.